# Suppose that $a < b$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is even. If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$...

Tags: real-analysis

and $\int_{b}^{a} f(x) \cdot x^n dx = 0$, show that $f(x) = 0$ for at least one $x \in [a,b]$.

My work so far:

Since $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, it's also integrable on $[a,b]$. This means we can apply the Mean Value Theorem for Integrals, and so

$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \cdot x^n dx = m \cdot \int_{a}^{c} x^n dx + M \cdot \int_{c}^{b} x^n dx$ for some $c \in [a,b]$, where $m, M \in \mathbb{R}$ and $m \leq$ inf$f([a,b])$ and $M \geq$ sup$f([a,b])$

I'm unsure if this is a good route to take, and if so what I should do next.

Comment: Just notice that $x^n > 0$ (with the exception of at most one point, which doesn't really matter) because $n$ is even. So if $f$ doesn't have a sign change, the integral is strictly positive or negative.

Comment: @T.Bongers Since OP is just asking for tips, this is as good as an answer as any.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about that. But I didn't know how to connect the dots. It implies that either $m$ or $M$ is negative and the other is positive, and to me that hints at the intermediate value theorem letting us conclude that f(x) = 0 at some point, but does it to suffice to say "Since either m or M is negative and the other positive, we can use the IVT to conclude that f(x) = 0 for some c between m and M" ?